# How to access current menu level/depth when overriding THEMENAME_menu_tree__MENU($variables)?

Tags: routes, theming

I'm creating a custom menu for a project built in Drupal 7 and I want to add some custom HTML before every UL in the main menu.

By adding the THEMENAME_menu_tree__main_menu($variables) function to my template.php I can output my custom HTML:

`return '<div>My custom HTML</div><ul class="main-menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';`

The function is called for every level in the menu and the HTML printed in front of every UL. But now I also want to customize this HTML in different ways for each level, but I cannot find any information regarding the current menu level in the $variables parameter.

Is it at all possible to access information about current menu level in the body of the function? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question is way past its expiry date, but who knows this might help someone :)

I must confess, I have never used this hook function before (`THEMENAME_menu_tree__main_menu`).  I had a quick look by implementing it in my current project, and you are only getting back HTML.  I think you are going to have a tough time styling individual items in the HTML you are getting back.

In my current project I render my menu a region template file (`region--header.tpl.php` to be exact).  Obviously this means I have a 'header' region defined in my `mytheme.info` file.

So in `page.tpl.php` I have

```
<?php
  if (isset($page['header'])) {
    print render($page['header']);
  }
?>
```

which basically defers rendering to `region--header.tpl.php` In this file I:

```
$menu = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
foreach ($menu as $menuItem) {
  // Extract info I want and render
  // $markup = ......
}

$print $markup
```

Basically I build my own HTML that will render the menu.

I have a couple of 'utility functions' to get the data out of $menuItem - let me know if you are interested.

As a side note - if you just want to figure out what level you are on - you could always call [menu_get_active_trail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_trail/7).  You should be able to figure out what 'level' you are on with the info in that array.

Hope this helps.